# Wall Mounted Bed and Desk

Tags: walls, mounting, load-bearing

Hello and thank you for taking your time to review my situation.

I am having some questions regarding how I would go about mounting a bed and desk to a wall. My goal is to have them solely attached to the walls to give it the appearance it is "floating" off the ground. The furniture will consist of a "full"  (or "double") size bed and a desk both on a single corner, although they will be on separate walls. What can I do to ensure a secure structure that will support more than enough weight of myself and a partner (200kg max)?

[image: Bed frame diagram]

If there is any more information I can provide or any other help you can give to me (building the bed frame the desk etc) would be much appreciated, although I am sure I can take my own time and find the knowledge myself.

Comment: The critical part is how deep/tall the bed or desk will be. A deep, thin desk is going to apply a whole lot of torque to the wall, as will a deep, thin bed. Shallower is better; taller is better.

Comment: Thank you Daniel for your response, I plan on keeping it fairly low to the ground, short enough I can freely touch the ground with my short legs, and what do you mean by "taller"? I have this idea where there would be a piece attached to the wall (studs) and then a piece perpendicular to that (attached to the wall AND the board) would extend outwards and act as my frame. From there I could add plywood boards or something similar to act as a surface for the table, and create a space for a bed frame on the bed side.

Comment: I wasn't clear: by "taller" I meant "a larger vertical footprint where the unit is fastened to the wall". I'm dubious you can do this for a bed.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying @DanielGriscom I have attached an image please let me know what you think. This was my idea initialy, although now i am worried it may not work

Comment: Your basically installing the equivalent of a small free hanging deck.  So you will need a ledger board to start.  If it will work would need adjusted based on your wall construction.